# $(1)$ $a\boxplus b=a+b-ab$ for all $a,b \in F$. $(2)$ $a\boxdot b=1-t^{\log_t{(1-a)}\log_t{(1-b)}}$ for all $a,b\in F$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, logarithms

> Let $1<t\in \mathbb{R}$ and let $F=\{a\in \mathbb{R}: a<1\}$. Define $\boxplus$ and $\boxdot$ on $F$ as follows:
>
> - $a \boxplus b=a+b-ab$ for all $a,b \in F$.
> - $a \boxdot b=1-t^{\log_t (1-a) \log_t (1-b)}$ for all $a,b\in F$
>
> For which values of $t$ does $F$, together with these operations, form a field?

I'm stuck on finding the possible $t$ values for this. Any help with the $t$ values is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please let us know where you are stuck and what attempts you have made.

Comment: What do you mean by $\log_t^{(1-a)}$? Do you mean $\log_t(1-a)$?

Comment: yes, sorry, I thought I typed that. I don't know how.

Comment: I'm unsure how to go about finding the $t$ values. I know that the multiplicative identity is $1-t$.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Explain better, please,$a\boxdot b$. You have always $t^{log_t{X}}=X$ and $t^{AB}=(t^A)^B=(t^B)^A$

Comment: Hint: in order for these operations to define a field, what axioms would they need to satisfy? Writing these down will give you equations involving $t$ that need to be solved.

Comment: I have shown that every field axiom is satisfied.

Comment: How exactly do I go about solving for $t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, let's check distributivity.

$\begin{align*}
a\boxdot(c\boxplus d)&=a\boxdot(c+d-cd)\\
&=1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-(c+d-cd))}\\
\end{align*}$

$\begin{align*}
(a\boxdot c)\boxplus (a\boxdot d)&=(1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-c)})\boxplus (1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-d))})\\
&= 1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-c)}+1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-d))}-(1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-c)})(1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-d))})\\
&= 1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-c)}-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-d))}\\
&+t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-c))}+t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-d))}-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-c)+
\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-d)}\\
&=1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-c)+
\log_t(1-a)\log_t(1-d)}\\
&=1-t^{\log_t(1-a)\log_t[(1-c)(1-d)]}
\end{align*}$

These expressions match, so they don't give any restriction on $t$ (except that $t>0$ in order for $\log_t$ to be defined.) Now check the other axioms similarly.